# How to create a single instance of object across entire Spring MVC web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, singleton, statsd

I have a Spring MVC web application (XML based without annotations). I want to create only one instance of **statsDClient** object on start of my application and use it across my whole application. I am trying something like below:

```
import com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClient;
import com.timgroup.statsd.StatsDClient;

Public class Helper(){

private static final StatsDClient statsDClient = new NonBlockingStatsDClient("prefix", "localhost", 8125);
private Helper(){}
 public static StatsDClient getInstance() {
      return statsDClient;
    }
}
```

Later in my controllers I am getting the **statsDClient** object in the following way:

```
public class HelpController extends AbstractController {
private StatsDClient statsDClient = Helper.getInstance();
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
statsDClient.someMethod();
}
```

But, this seems to be creating creating a new **statsDClient** object everything I use it in different controllers. Can you please guide where am I going wrong?

Comment: Implement Singleton correctly

Comment: Just register it as a bean and inject it.

Comment: This is the normal mode for Spring beans (singleton mode). Just make it a Spring bean, and everything will work for you automatically. Note that you seem to be using an _ancient_ tutorial, as I personally have been using Spring for 10 years and have never once written a controller that used `AbstractController`, and you will _usually_ want to use the Spring Boot Micrometer tools instead of statsd directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beans in spring is by default singleton, which means only one shared instance is ever created and being managed by the spring container through out the entire application.

So in your case, you *don't need* to specify statsDClient to be a single instance,

you could do something like

to ensure statsDClient would have been instantiated once only
but it's just redundant

Pls refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-singleton for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Variables that marked static was created only once in memory. You can create a bean and inject it wherever you need.

Comment: Do I need to create a bean of Helper class or NonBlockingStatsDClient class directly?

Comment: Actually, you can do both, but in this case, you can create a bean of NonBlockingStatsDClient.